# How to generate nine uniform points in (0,1) conditional on the event than no two of them are within 0.1 each other by MCMC Hasting-Metropolis method?

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo

I'm learning on statistic simulation, and want to solve the MCMC problem which was described on the topic. I know the ith element has 0.8^k probability to be found. How could I define the target pdf and proposal function in order to execute the accpet-rejection-like process?

Comment: Be careful!  Due to edge effects, the chance is not $0.8^k.$  If you want to avoid some of this problem, generate points uniformly on a circle.